# I can't install Ubuntu from bootable pendrive, but other distros work fine

Tags: ubuntu, reinstall

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04. I want to reinstall ubuntu (cause I think the current one is corrupted) The only problem is, it boots into the current OS even though I connected the bootable pendrive/thumb-drive/usb-stick and configured it on the BIOS. I thought it was a problem with the usb but any other distro work fine (I tried fedora and arch). Here's some more info:

Current OS: Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64
Pendrive: SanDisk 64Gigabyte
ISO file in the pendrive: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64
ISO Source: [Ubuntu's official site](https://ubuntu.com/#download) - CLICKING WILL START THE DOWNLOAD!
Tool I used to burn it onto the usb: BalenaEtcher and Startup disk creator

Comment: What tool did you use to make your bootable pendrive? I've faced with those problems and sometimes the tool can be the problem. Try to make your bootable usb with different tools like `dd` command or softwares like `balenaEtcher` , `ventoy` or `unetbootin`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I tried with Startup disk creator (the tool that comes by default on ubuntu) and balenaEtcher too.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with UEFI or Legacy mode. Have you tried to change that?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I'll consider checking that too, but shouldn't wrong boot mode not let me boot into ubuntu in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure. What I do remember is that always have my BIOS in UEFI mode when I want to boot through the bootable USB.